# Assassins Creed 3 PC Visual and Camera Issues

Tags: technical-issues, assassins-creed-3

Assassins Creed 3 on PC has been unbearable to play. When sailing out on the open sea, I will often notice flickering textures or various camera issues.

[image: Flickering Textures - AC3]

& [Camera issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/no8d2.jpg)

**PC Specs are:**

- Intel i7 CPU @3.60GHz
- 16GB DDR3 Ram
- NVidia GeForce GTX 960 2GB
- HDD 2TB
- Native 1080p 60Hz Monitor

So far I have tried:

- Uninstall/install the game
- Lower Visual and Environmental effects

Is there a possible fix for these issues, or perhaps AC3 just suffers from a bad PC port?

Comment: The second gif absolutely refuses to upload; Hence the link, my apologies.

Comment: This looks like a shader issue, but honestly I am not sure anyone can give a definitive answer as to what you should change to fix it. When was the last time you updated your graphics drivers? Are you using any kind of advanced options? Have you overclocked your card?

Comment: I shall edit my question to better reflect what it is exactly that I am looking for, as for your questions, my card is fully up-to-date, no and no.

Comment: AC3 has its fair share of graphical glitches. I personally suffered from the same multi-core bug that plagues other Ubisoft titles in this game. I never encountered that flickering though, or I would never have finished the game. http://steamcommunity.com/id/Sumurai8/screenshots/?appid=208480&sort=newestfirst&browsefilter=myfiles&view=grid

Comment: Weird thing is I almost have the same specs, only 8gb ddr3 and it runs perfectly so I really can't say

Comment: @Samurai8, It's interesting that you got so many bugs and I've got so little bugs while play this game.

Comment: @Mano, No other games happen that?